# Discord.py- How to make a bot message the server prefix when its pinged?

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I wanted my bot to send the prefix of that particular server when it pinged (mentioned).

I did google it but it didn't work ([Discord.py- How to make a bot message when its pinged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64317659/discord-py-how-to-make-a-bot-message-when-its-pinged))

it stops from other commands being executed, etc.

this is my code

```
import random
import json
from discord.ext import commands
import numpy
from urllib.request import urlopen as url
from discord.ext.commands import cooldown, BucketType
#testbot
def get_prefix(client, message):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)
    
    return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = get_prefix)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'bots up')

@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)
    
    prefixes[str(guild.id)] = '.'
    with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)

@bot.event
async def on_guild_remove(guild):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)
    
    prefixes.pop(str(guild.id))
    with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)

@bot.command()
async def setprefix(ctx, prefix):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)
    
    prefixes[str(ctx.guild.id)] = prefix
    with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)
    await ctx.send(f'prefix set to: {prefix}')

@bot.command(description='check bot ping type .ping')
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'{round(bot.latency*1000)}ms')
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if bot.user.mentioned_in(message):
        print("pinged")
        await message.channel.send('My prefix here is {0} '.format(bot.command_prefix))


bot.run('token')
```

sends me this message instead

**<function get_prefix at 0xb55a16a8>**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `on_message` event to check when your bot is mentioned.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if bot.user.mentioned_in(message) and message.mention_everyone is False:
        prefix= get_prefix
        await message.channel.send(f"My prefix is {bot.command_prefix}")

     await bot.process_commands(message) # This line makes your other commands work.
```

The last line is probably your solution to the commands stopping to work after using `on_message` event.

Comment: This will get triggered everytime the bot it's mentioned, even in a long message like `@bot#1234 hello world`

Comment: What does tht extra line do?

Comment: I added tht line but sends same sentence
*<function get_prefix at 0xb55a16a8>*

Comment: Your `get_prefix` is not returning the prefix. That's why.